# Running Android task or method in background?

Tags: android, background, ping

What I'm trying to do is when the Activity is started the app will ping servers to see if they're online. The current problem is, the app will freeze and become unusable until it has pinged all the servers. So what I have now is:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
       //ping stuff
}};
t.start();
```

And that eliminates the freezing issue, but it doesn't seem to be actually pinging anything. What it does after pining is changing a textview from "Server Status" to either "Server Status Online" or "Server Status Offline" and that is not happening. Here is the ping method I am using:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try{
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 sfb.noip.me");
                    int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess2 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 sg.lbsg.net");
                    int mExitValue2 = mIpAddrProcess2.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess3 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 peepzcraft.zapto.org");
                    int mExitValue3 = mIpAddrProcess3.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess4 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 71.226.128.188");
                    int mExitValue4 = mIpAddrProcess4.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess5 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 playmcpe.com");
                    int mExitValue5 = mIpAddrProcess5.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess6 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 survival.dgpocket.us");
                    int mExitValue6 = mIpAddrProcess6.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess7 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 minecraft.blocksandgold.com");
                    int mExitValue7 = mIpAddrProcess7.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess8 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 pe.cookie-build.com");
                    int mExitValue8 = mIpAddrProcess8.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess9 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 96.8.119.195");
                    int mExitValue9 = mIpAddrProcess9.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess10 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 Play.mcpe-ba.info");
                    int mExitValue10 = mIpAddrProcess10.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess12 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 leet.cc");
                    int mExitValue12 = mIpAddrProcess12.waitFor();
                    Process  mIpAddrProcess13 = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 ru.24serv.pro");
                    int mExitValue13 = mIpAddrProcess13.waitFor();

                    if(mExitValue==0){

                        text.setText("Server Status: Online");              
                    }else{
                        text.setText("Server Status: Offline");              
                    }
                    if(mExitValue2==0){
                        text2.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text2.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue3==0){
                        text3.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text3.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue4==0){
                        text4.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text4.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue5==0){
                        text5.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text5.setText("Server Statis: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue6==0){
                        text6.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text6.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue7==0){
                        text7.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text7.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue8==0){
                        text8.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text8.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue9==0){
                        text9.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text9.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue10==0){
                        text10.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text10.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue12==0){
                        text12.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text12.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                    if(mExitValue13==0){
                        text13.setText("Server Status: Online");
                    }else{
                        text13.setText("Server Status: Offline");
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
                return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android's `AsyncTask` to accomplish your task.

Ping the servers in the `doInBackground`().

Return the results to `onPostExecute`() & set the TextViews.

You can't update the Views from background as your current code.